# Saving group of items from a list

Tags: c#, list

What I am trying to accomplish is to group my list by supplier id.  Iterate over that list calculate stuff etc and when finished pass that list on to save and clear the list out and start over again.  The error is the : "collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute. c#".  Now from [googling](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2015/02/28/enumerating-collections-that-change-in-csharp/) it I'm just suming then pass that group off to save and clear the list rinse and repeat.  I thought the clear would empty the list and allow for reuse.

Error - "collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute. c#"

group is grouping the list that is passed in to this method.

I created the count to see how many groups I had(6).

ProcessSpecialOrders receives a grouped list, po and the total.

What happens here is this will process through the first group once. Save to the DB then it will throw the error.  If I refresh my page or check the DB I can see grop one has saved.

```
           List<xxxxx> specialOrderList = new List<xxxxx>(); 
        var group = from supplier in list group supplier by supplier.SupplierId;

        var count = group.Count();
        foreach (var grp in group.ToList())
        {
            specialOrderList.Clear();
            foreach (var g in grp.ToList())
            {
                var orderItemList = new MOrderItem();
                if (g.ItemType == "SD")
                {                        
                    xxx.Id = 0;
                    xxx.ItemId = g.Id;
                    xxx.OnHandQty = g.OnHand;
                    xxx.ItemNo = g.ItemNumber;
                    xxx.ThisQty = 0;
                    xxx.NetCost = itemPrice.Where(x => x.ItemId == g.Id).Sum(l => (decimal?)l.NetCost * 1) ?? 0.0M;
                    xxx.ExtendedCost = 123.99M;
                    xxx.OnHandWhenBuildQty = 0;
                    xxx.OnOrderQty = matcoOrderItem.Where(x => x.ItemId == g.Id).Sum(x => (int?)x.ThisQty) ?? 0;
                    specialOrderList.Add(orderItemList);    
                }
            }
            ProcessSpecialOrders(specialOrderList, poNo, specialOrderTotal);
        }
```

Comment: And what error is thrown? Post exception please

Comment: What are you trying to do by clearing `specialOrderList`? You can't clear it because `group` depends on it and you are iterating over `group`.

Comment: Why not call the constructor instead of clearing? specialOrderList = new List<xxxxx>();

Comment: @TroyBryant What are *xxxxx* and *xxx*? Don't you think it will be easier to understand your code once you use proper identifiers?